# How do I add prefabs to the list at once

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

[example prefabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO5rG.png)
i have lots of prefab in assets(not in hierarchy). i want to instantiate one prefab randomly. but how can add prefab list or array once . it mean i have a 600 prefab and

```
List<GameObject> example= new List<Gameobject>();
exapmle.add(...);
exapmle.add(...);
exapmle.add(...);
exapmle.add(...);
...
```

How do I make it simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like you want to load many prefabs into one large list without having to load each one individually. If this is the case, you can use the following:

```
public GameObject[] allPrefabs;

void Start()
{
    allPrefabs = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Prefabs");
}
```

If you really want them in a list, not an array, you can convert this array to a list with the following:

```
List<GameObject> example = new List<GameObject>(allPrefabs);
```

This could be slow though if you have a lot of prefabs.

**A Note:** In order to use `Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Prefabs")`, you will need to have a folder named "Prefabs" within a folder named "Resources" within your "Assets" folder.

Comment: in my question have a picture "example prefabs" please look at this is my asset folder. if i'm understand correctly i write 
allPrefabs = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Sorular");
is it true?

Comment: @Nurullah In unity, anything that begins with `Resources.` will specifically look for a folder titled "Resources" within your "Assets" folder. So you would need to put your "Sorular" folder within a new folder entitled "Resources". **Then** you could do `allPrefabs = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Sorular")`

Comment: @Nurullah Glad I could help